# How to get a report for each group using Wilcoxon test

Tags: r, report, pairwise.wilcox.test

This code gives a report independently of the variable `Session`. How can I obtain two reports, one for each `Session`, using a Wilcoxon paired test?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(report)


df <- tibble(Session = c(rep("1", 10), rep("2", 10)),
             scores = sample(20:70, 20),
             group = c(rep("before", 5), rep("after",5),
                       rep("before", 5), rep("after",5)))

wilcox.test(df$scores ~ df$group, paired = TRUE) |> report()
#> Effect sizes were labelled following Funder's (2019) recommendations.
#> 
#> The Wilcoxon signed rank exact test testing the difference in ranks between
#> df$scores and df$group suggests that the effect is negative, statistically not
#> significant, and small (W = 24.00, p = 0.770; r (rank biserial) = -0.13, 95% CI
#> [-0.68, 0.52])
```

Comment: It's unclear to me, what you like to achieve. Perhaps `split(df, df$Session)`?

Comment: @Friede I think `split`may help. I want to get a report for Session 1 and another for Session 2. I tried `group_by` before but without success.

Comment: `lapply( split( …` would be old school R but I’m sure that `group_by` should work as well.